# How to get the polygon vs. Polygon Intersection Coordinates using python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I want to find the intersection coordinates between two polygons.

```
aLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
selection = aLayer.selectedFeatures()
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.permutations(selection,r=2):
    intersect=geom1.geometry().intersection(geom2.geometry())
    intersect_list=intersect.asPolyline()
    count=len(intersect_list)
```

Its giving the intersection geometry but when i am converting that as a polyline to get the intersection vertices it is giving empty list. Here what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure of what i'm saying but ... : **asPolyline** should return (if working) a **QgsPolyline** object ... i don't think **len(a QgsPolyline)** has any meaning ...

Comment: You need to consider the different possibilities for the geometry of polygon features intersection. However, it is preferable to express the geometry directly as WKT because the code is more concise and it is easier to get a memory layer. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the different possibilities for the geometry of polygon features intersection. Options could be a point, line or polygon. However, it is preferable to express the geometry directly as WKT because the code is more concise and it is easier to get a memory layer.

To try out my approach, first, I modified your code to:

```
import itertools

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

aLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
selection = aLayer.selectedFeatures()
n=len(selection)
list = range(n)

for i,j in itertools.combinations(list, 2):
    geom = selection[i].geometry().intersection(selection[j].geometry())
    print geom.exportToWkt()
```

After running it with a two features shapefile, where the intersection is a polygon, I got:`

[image]

I used the QuickWKT plugin to put the polygon layer visible at the Map Canvas.

At the next situation, the features are adjacent and the intersection is a LineString; where the QuickWKT plugin was also used to visualize the line layer at the Map View.

[image]

I hope that it helps.